# Archivos en ListBox C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Buenos dias estimados colegas ,

solicito su asesoría frente a lo siguiente , tengo la opción openfiledialog.multiselect la cual me carga una serie de archivos a un listbox , la cuestión es que cuando deseo trabajar con los archivos cargados en ese listbox no me arroja nada , es decir por ejemplo requiero que los items en el listbox sean convertidos de pdf a word , cuando hago la conversión , solo me selecciona el primero de esa lista , ayuda por favor

```
DialogResult Resultado = CajaDialogo.ShowDialog();

if (Resultado == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{ 
    foreach(string filename in CajaDialogo.FileNames) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(filename); 
        Lista.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(filename));
    }

    foreach (var item in Lista.Items) 
    {
        string file = item.ToString(); 
        RutaArchivoOrigen= file.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Nos muestras lo que llevas hecho hasta ahora? Asi podemos ver donde tienes problemas y ayudarte mejor :)

Comment: como accedes a los items de listbox ?

Comment: Claro que si NaCi , muchas gracias

Comment: Hola  DialogResult Resultado = CajaDialogo.ShowDialog();

 if (Resultado == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
  {
foreach (string filename in CajaDialogo.FileNames)
{
MessageBox.Show(filename);
Lista.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(filename));                    
 }
foreach (var item in Lista.Items)
 {

string file = item.ToString();
RutaArchivoOrigen= file.ToString();

 }

}   los archovs seleccionados conOpenfiledialog.multiselect aparecen en el listBox , pero cuando intento trabajar con esos archivos no me permite acceder como a las propiedades etc

Comment: No pongas el codigo en los comentarios. Pulsa en [edit] y añadelo ahi :)

Comment: Muchas gracias Naci soy nuevo en estos foros de Desarrollo , gracias